# Vuetify v-slider - execute function after change of value (v-slider)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dojo, vuetify.js

I am trying to execute a function when the v-slider is used (using dojo/on), but my approach doesn't work. Do you have any idea what I should change?

https://codepen.io/hjmd/pen/bjGLoJ

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
       <v-slider v-model="sliderValue"
                    id="sliderId"
                    v-on:input="sliderInput"
                    :max="2018"
                    :min="1990"
                    step="1"
                    thumb-label
                    ticks></v-slider>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    sliderValue: 1990
  }),
  methods: {
    sliderInput (e) {
      this.sliderValue = e
      return this.sliderValue
    }
  },
  mounted  () {
    require(["dojo/on"], function(on){
      var slider = document.getElementById('sliderId')
      var vm = this
      function SomeFunction() {
        console.log('SomeFunction executed')
      }
      on(slider, 'change', function (event) {
        var xyz = vm.sliderValue
        SomeFunction(xyz)
      })
    })
   }
  })
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `v-on:change` attribute? I don't see the point of using dojo here

Comment: Vuetify's `v-slider` has both `@change` and `@input` events. `@change` is normally triggered when the slider losses focus, whereas `@input` will trigger after the value changes.

Comment: The codepen is missing.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you have got the answer to it but if not, you can use: @change="function"

Comment: Can you provide a little more information?  Where exactly should the `@change="function"` go?

Comment: <v-slider @change="function"></v-slider>

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how the `vuetify` library works neither the `dojo`, but I'm familiar with the `VUE`. The `v-model` is essentially syntax sugar for updating data on user input events, you could replace it with `v-bind` and `v-on:input`. So it's wrong you bind `sliderInput` with `input event` again.